# Different outputs for almost same programs in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, printf

Sample 1:

```
char a []={'h','i'};
int i;
for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
printf("%c",a[i]);
}
printf("%s",a);
```

> > Output: hi☻hi♥

Sample 2:

```
char a []={'h','i'};
int i;
for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
    char l = a[i];
    printf("%c",a[i]);
}
printf("%s",a);
```

> > Output:hii♥hi♥♦

Sample 3:

```
char a [5]={'h','i'};
int i;
for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){
printf("%c",a[i]);
}
printf("%s",a);
```

> > Output: hihi

Why the output of these three programs are dissimilar?

Sample 1 and sample 2 are almost similar code except an extra line `char l = a[i]` and Sample 3 is different from sample 1 and 2 based on the declaration of the size of the array.

Comment: Passing invalid argument to `printf` (non-terminated string instead of terminated) causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 5):

In C, arrays only have a size, but no terminator. So an array of two characters (like your first two examples) will have the two characters you specified and nothing else. When you loop looking for the "terminator" you will go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

The third case is different, because there you define an array of five elements but only initialize the first two. The C standard then requires the rest of the array to be initialized to zero, which is the same as the character `'\0'`. The array in the third example still haven't got an explicit terminator though, it just so happens that the remainder is initialized the same value as the string terminator.

Answer (score 3):

For sample 1 and 2, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by passing a non-null terminated array as argument to `%s` in `printf()`.

For a definition like

```
 char a []={'h','i'};
```

`a` will be allocated memory to hold only two elements, there will be no extra space allocated to store a terminating null, in this case of using brace-enclosed initializer list.

Quoting Chapter §7.21.6.1, for use of `%s` format specifier with `printf()` family,

> `s` 
>  If no l length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.<sup>280)</sup> **Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character**. If the
>   precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written. **If the
>   precision is not specified** or is greater than the size of the array, **the array shall
>   contain a null character.**

OTOH, in case of sample 3, for a definition like

```
char a [5]={'h','i'};
```

the array **is** null-terminated, so the output is proper. The array is null-terminated in this case, because, you have provided the array size at the time of declaration and supplied less number of initiliazers in the brace enclosed list, so the remaining elements are initialized to `0` (as if they have `static` storage). Related, `C11`, chapter §6.7.9, (*emphasis mine*)

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul because of UB, please see the quoted link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For `printf("%s",a)` to work, the memory block pointed by `a` must end with 0.

Same thing goes for the code starting with `for (i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)`.

In all of your examples, this memory block ends with `'i'`, not with 0.

You can fix it by changing the initialization of `a` to either one of the following:

- `char a[] = {'h','i',0};`
- `char a[] = {'h','i','\0'};`
- `char a[] = "hi";`
- `char *a  = "hi";`

Comment: Please note that the first three options are equivalent, whereas in the last option, the contents of the memory block pointed by `a` are non-modifiable.